# CodeIgniter manage records from database

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am having a trouble coming up with the concept of this. My application is stored in `http://localhost` (duh) and I have an admin panel, which can be accessed by going to `http://localhost/admin`. I have admin panel menu and one of the menus is Manage Pages, accessed by going to `http://localhost/admin/manage_pages`. Manage Pages page brings up results from database which have title, description and ID. Now, my question is, if I want to edit lets say the third row's title, how would I do this? would it be `http://localhost/admin/manage_pages/3`? But for that case I would have to create a function in controller? I am confused.

Comment: There are several ways to go about this, but I think if you study CodeIgniter's routing it will make more sense. Fundamentally, your controller is admin, the function is manage_pages, and any other data in the url (like 3) you can get using the URI class. So no, you don't need a new function for each page.

Comment: this makes sense, since anything after manage_pages can be retrieved/sent/retrieved and be compared to the id value of the row. Thanks for the hint!

Comment: you can do other way also if you had any edit button. When you click on edit button call a javascript function. In that function load a colorbox from color box just write a simple controller function. In that pass the id and use that id to retrieve the details about that page from database and show it in the colorbox in editable text boxes. Once after you edit done update in the database when user submits it using again id.

Answer (score 1):

If you like the way the URI is formatted: localhost/admin/manage_pages/3, then the onlt thing you are missing is to accept a variable for your controller function. In this instance I prefer to set a default value if none was passed, and with an if else statement, you have a method that will load the specified page, or load all pages when nothing is passed.

Controller admin:

```
public function manage_pages($page_id='')
{
    if ($page_id == '')
    {    LOAD ALL RESULTS }
    else
    {    LOAD 1 RESULT    }
}
```